# Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Navigating event raised on iOS for internal navigation

Tags: c#, ios, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Let's say you want to prevent the user from navigating away from your Xamarin.Forms.WebView to an external page.

```
public App ()
{
    var webView = new WebView
    {
        Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
        {
            Html = "<h1>Hello world</h1><a href='http://example.com'>Can't escape!</a><iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
        }
    };
    webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;

    MainPage = new ContentPage {
        Content = webView
    };
}

private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // we don't want to navigate away from our page
    // open it in a new page instead etc.
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This works fine on Windows and Android. But on iOS, it doesn't load at all!

On iOS, the Navigating event gets raised even when loading the source from a HtmlWebViewSource, with a URL that looks something like `file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[deviceID]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[appID]/[appName].app/`

Alright, so you can get around that with something like this:

```
private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.StartsWith("file:") == false)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The page finally loads on iOS. Yay. But wait! The embedded YouTube video doesn't load! That's because the **Navigating event gets raised for the internal navigation** of embedded resources like iframes and even external scripts (like Twitter's `<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>`), but only on iOS!

I couldn't find a way to determine if the Navigating event was raised from internal navigation or because the user clicked a link.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible to detect in Xamarin Forms out of the box but the navigation type is easily determined using a custom renderer. In your custom iOS renderer, assign a WebViewDelegate and within that Delegate class, override `ShouldStartLoad()` like so:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer {

    #region Properties

    public CustomWebView CustomWebViewItem { get { return Element as CustomWebView; } }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.OldElement == null) {
            Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate(); //Assigning the delegate
        }
    }
}
internal class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate {

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType) {

        if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked) {
            //To prevent navigation when a link is click, return false
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You could also surface a bool property or even an enum back up to your Xamarin Forms `WebView` which would say whether the `Navigating` event was from a link being clicked or from something else, though a custom renderer would be needed for that as well.

Comment: Thank you it works great. Have you any kind of idea of how to impolite this with a custom renderer for android ? Because I use a custom renderer and a custom WebViewClient, the OnNavigating event from the WebView isn't fired anymore.

Comment: @Nk54 You can simply overwrite the WebView's current `OnNavigating` with one that is triggered within your custom renderer. This is probably better suited in a new questions but that is annoying so I will point you to a link showing a custom `OnNavigating` property being created, [here](https://github.com/seansparkman/CookiesWebView/blob/master/Cookies.Android/CookieWebViewRenderer.cs#L45). Then if you look [here](https://github.com/seansparkman/CookiesWebView/blob/master/Cookies/CookieWebView.cs#L20),l just add the word `new` to the property which will overwrite the default `OnNavigating`

Comment: @Nk54 So the property would become `public new event WebViewNavigatingHandler Navigating;`. Just make sure to include all the other event wiring code within `CookieWebView.cs`. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: @hvaughan3 please give explanation. CustomWebViewRenderer  class wrote in ios inside render class it customwebview get error and how to call from forms and xaml file also give explaniation

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri Are you asking how to create the custom renderer itself? There should be guides on how to do that within the Xamarin Forms documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool isNavigated = false;
        public CustomWebView()
        {
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
            {
                // always true for android
                isNavigated = true;
            }

            Navigated += (sender, e) =>
            {
                isNavigated = true;
            };
            Navigating += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (isNavigated)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri(e.Url);
                        Device.OpenUri(uri);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }

                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe your code so that other users that view this question can understand it with more ease.

Comment: This little piece of code helped me solve a similar issue.