# Xamarin Forms: Webview on IOS opens IFrames automatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

my problem is that I open my website in a webview, which has widgets like twitter and youtube and they are opened automatically without clicking on it. I have tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298586/xamarin-forms-webview-navigating-event-raised-on-ios-for-internal-navigation). But the webview page doesn't open anymore. Unfortunately I don't know much about custom renderers.
Thanks for your help

That's how my custom renderer looks like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), 

typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]

namespace dApp.iOS
{

  public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
  {

    #region Properties

    public CustomWebView CustomWebViewItem { get { return Element as CustomWebView; } }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate(); //Assigning the delegate
        }
    }
   }

  internal class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
   {

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {

        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
        {
            //To prevent navigation when a link is click, return false
            return false;
        }

        return true;
     }
    }
}
```